# How can I write a python requests test for my login API written in Flask which renders the HTML form for the same?

Tags: python, html, flask, testing, python-requests

I have been trying to write basic login test using the python requests module. I designed the API endpoints using Flask which renders the HTML pages. Below is the HTML form for the login:

```
    <form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="post" id="login" >
        <div class="msg"><p class = "messagep">{{ msg }}</p></div>
        <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" >Username</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <span>Remember me</span> </br></br>
    <div class="right">
        <a style="font-family: 'Arial';" href="#">Forgot Password</a>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light mb-2" name="log" >Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

The Flask API endpoint for login is as below:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        if not username or not password:
            msg = 'Please enter your username/password!'
            return render_template('login.html', msg=msg)
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s AND password = %s", [username, password])
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        if account:
            session['loggedin'] = True
            # session['id'] = account['id']
            session['username'] = account['username']
            session['fname'] = account['first_name']
            msg = 'Logged in successfully !'
            return redirect(url_for("home"))
        else:
            msg = 'Incorrect username / password !'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        msg = 'Please fill out the form !'
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        uname = session.get("username", "Unknown")
        if uname == "Unknown":
            return render_template('login.html')
        else:
            return redirect(url_for("home"))
    return render_template('login.html', msg=msg)
```

The Python requests test for this is as below:

```
def check_sign_in():
    try:
        credentials = {'username': 'test', 'password': ''}
        session = requests.Session()
        response = session.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/login', data=credentials)
        assert response.status_code == 200
        print('Sign in successful!')
    except AssertionError as e:
        print('Sign in error!')
        e.args += ('Received response code:', response.status_code)
        raise
```

My worry now is that this test always passes even if I give incorrect credentials like in the above case, an empty password. I tried a lot of different approaches but still don't understand why it keeps passing. However, this feature seems to work properly when testing manually.

Comment: Not sure but I think the line where you check if the account with given username and password exist or not you should also redirect the user to login page if he/she hits this else block `else:msg = 'Incorrect username / password !'`. Add `return redirect(url_for('home'))` after this statement.

Comment: I did not add that because basically, home page is the home page of the user. If the credentials are incorrect, the user shouldn't be redirected to that page.